# Why does nuget's behavior re getting the latest package seem inconsistent?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

Let's assume that there is one project depended on the **xunit v 1.9.1** package and its output assembly is published as nuget package. 
Now, if the package is installed using the `Install-Package` command, the depended xunit package will be installed as **v1.9.2** not v1.9.1.

I cannot observe this case in other packages. Is there any point making this case?

At this question, the nuget version is [v2.7](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.7).

---

[update]

The following code snippet is part of the nuspec file of my test project mentioned above.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="xunit" version="1.9.1" />
  <dependency id="Moq" version="4.0.10827"/>
</dependencies>
```

When I install my test project, the Moq package was installed as the same version specified above but the recent Moq version is [v4.1.1308.2321](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/), which is not breaking change according to semver. On the contrary, the xunit package was installed as the lastest **v 1.9.2**.

Comment: I would expect that pother packages would act the same way, and the most recent is installed unless you specify other ways. What I experience sometimes, is when I gradually upgrade versions from my own nuget repo, sometimes nuget doesn't automatically remove the traces of the old package, although it is not used anywhere any more. But that's another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the package manifest.  If you are letter the `pack` command detect the dependencies from a `csproj`, the it will specify the version as 1.9.1.  However, NuGet treats this as the min version, not the required version.

See  http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Specifying_Version_Ranges_in_.nuspec_Files

Now, because the new version is 1.9.2, it is not considered a breaking change per Semantic Versioning, therefore it is safe to install.

See http://semver.org/

Also note this blog post as to how NuGet resolves versions.  That is, it will install the latest patch for a specified Major and Minor version.

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/nuget-versioning-part-2-core-algorithm.html

Comment: @Jin-WookChung Please refer to the first link in my answer.  Specifying a version means that is the minimum version required, not the specific version.

Comment: Yes, however, the moq package will not be updated to a recent version automatically even if its version is not breaking change.

Comment: Looks like it will get the newest version of a given Major and Minor version.  See http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/nuget-versioning-part-2-core-algorithm.html

Comment: Oh yes, it is the just point of my question. The author, David, mentions this as **“1.1 twist”**. Could you add the reference link to your answer to accept? Thank you for your effort and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify a version explicitly? If not, then I'm not surprised at all that 1.9.2 is installed, since that's most recent, and it's backward compatible with 1.9.1.

This is an expected behavior of package management systems in general, that if you don't specify version explicitly, it'll try to grab the newest ones.

You can change that behavior at the project's reference entry (telling exact or minimal version number). Things can also depend on the meta-data of nuget packages.